# How do i slant my container section corner in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello Developers I have been trying to design my container like the picture to get a slanted section of the container corner

[image: slanted corner container in flutter]]

in flutter but have not been able to any help or package name will be greatly appreciated thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to build a custom clipper.

Something like below will define your clipper but do adjust to your specifics:

```
class SlantedCornerClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.75, 0); 
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

You can then wrap your widget with this custom clipper that you created. Something like below:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: SlantedCornerClipper(),
      child: Container(
        width: 300.0,
        height: 200.0,

      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: try using the path by extending `ShapeBorder`.